# secure url change whitout a working backend

Tags: php, magento, ssl

Since yesterday I have a ssl cert. But now my hosting people tell me that I have to change my url code from http:// to https://. I cant do that in the magento store backend because that looks like a kind of html code and any changes it doesn't pick it up.

In my backend I used to fix the thing in the 'web' part and I looked in PHPMysql in the core config data there it stands correctly.

Can I change it somewhere else in ftp? it yes where?
Or is it totally something else were I have to look at?

my website looks like this now:[natuurmake-up](https://www.natuurmake-up.nl)
Maybe it is simple, but I am not an expert so I could use some help.

Comment: What?! "I have to fix the url" - "fix"? Which URL? In which way? "in the backend" What kind of "backend" is that? "in the 'web' part" - ...?! - Please make some serious improvement on your question.

Comment: I have to change url from http://   www.natuurmake-up.nl to https://  natuurmake-up.nl in the backend of my magento store. in admin-configuratoin-system-algemeen-Web there I could change the secure url. But now, the store-backend from magento is not working.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll do my best in english on this new forum.

Comment: Knowing that you're using magento was *really, really* critical to understand what you're talking about. "Backend" alone has absolutely no meaning besides being the opposite of "frontend".

Comment: Oke, thanks. Than i know for next time